# Stuck with input's delay on onchange event in Form's component. Sending data to API is ok. datasByParameter array's of object length may be the issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, dom

I've got this following code in `Form.js` file.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './Form.module.css';
import CheckboxComponent from './Checkbox';
import handleDataSubmit from './DataSubmit';
import useFetch from './hooks/useFetch';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

const getInputType = (value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
    return 'checkbox';
  }
  return 'text';
};


export default function Form({ urlGetData, apiUrlPostUpdate }) {
  /**
   * Dynamic form component to display and update company data.
   *
   * @param {string} urlGetData - The API URL for [GET] fetching company data.
   * @param {string} apiUrlPostUpdate - The API URL for [POST] sending updated company data.
   * @returns {JSX.Element} Form component.
   */


  const [datasByParameter, setDatasByParameter] = useFetch(urlGetData);
  const [dataFieldsProperties, setDataFeildsProperties] = useFetch(`${urlGetData}/fields_properties`)


  // Handlers 
  const handlerAtivarEdicao = (divId, event) => {
    let buttonCaller = event.target

    let divForm = document.getElementById(divId)
    let _inputs = divForm.querySelectorAll('input')
    // Use slice to ignore the first input
    const inputsToToggle = Array.from(_inputs).slice(1);

    inputsToToggle.forEach((input) => {
      input.disabled = !input.disabled
    })

    if (inputsToToggle[0].disabled) {
      buttonCaller.textContent = 'ALLOW EDITION'

    } else {
      buttonCaller.textContent = 'PROTECT EDITION'
    }

  };

  const handleLabelClick = (event) => {
    const input = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    const previousDisabledState = input.disabled
    input.disabled = false;
    input.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    input.disabled = previousDisabledState;
  };


  const handleInputChange = (clientIndex, key, value) => {
    const updatedClients = [...datasByParameter];
    const updatedClient = { ...updatedClients[clientIndex] };

    updatedClient[key] = value;

    updatedClients[clientIndex] = updatedClient;

    setDatasByParameter(updatedClients);

    const responseData = handleDataSubmit(apiUrlPostUpdate, updatedClient);

  };

  /*const handleSubmit = async (e, clientIndex) => {
    const responseData = await handleDataSubmit(apiUrlPostUpdate, dadosPorParametro[clientIndex]);
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Response:', responseData);
  };*/

  // Setting Empresas Inputs
  const showInputs = (clientData, clientIndex) => {
    return Object.entries(clientData).map(([key, value], indx) => {
      let input_id = `${clientData['id']}_${key}`;
      let input_type = getInputType(value);
      // TODO: check this part
      let inputsMaxLength
      try {
        inputsMaxLength = dataFieldsProperties['inputs_max_length'][indx]
      }
      catch {
        inputsMaxLength = 255
      }
      // console.log(inputsMaxLength)

      return (
        <div className={styles.inputsContainer} key={input_id}>
          {/* Todo: remover o onclick do input_type checkbox */}
          <label onClick={handleLabelClick} htmlFor={input_id}>
            {key}
          </label>
          {input_type === 'checkbox' ? (
            <CheckboxComponent
              id={key}
              // onChange={(e) => handleInputBlur(clientIndex, key, e.target.value)}
              defaultValue={value}
              clabel="STATUS ATIVO" />
          ) : (
            <input
              type={input_type}
              id={input_id}
              name={input_id}
              value={clientData[key]}
              onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(clientIndex, key, e.target.value)}
              // onBlur={(e) => handleInputBlur(clientIndex, key, e.target.value)}
              // disabled={key !== 'id'}
              disabled={true}
              maxLength={inputsMaxLength !== -1 ? inputsMaxLength : undefined}
            // Na minha lógica, inputs sem essa propriedade, recebem -1 
            />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  let getDivFormName = (name) => `form-client-${name}`;

  // Component
  return (
    <div className={styles.clientContainer}>
      {datasByParameter.map((clientData, index) => (
        <div id={getDivFormName(index)} key={index} className={styles.clientColumn}>
          <form
            // onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, index)} 
            method='POST'>
            <Button variant="contained" color="success" onClick={(event) => handlerAtivarEdicao(getDivFormName(index), event)}>
              Allow Edition
            </Button>
            {showInputs(clientData, index)}
            {/* <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /> */}
          </form>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

There goes my `hooks/useFetch.js` as well

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';

export default function useFetch(url, options) {

  /**
   * Custom React hook for making data fetch requests.
   * @param {string} url - The URL to fetch data from.
   * @returns {Array} An array containing the fetched data.
   */

  const makeUrl = (endpoint) => new URL(endpoint, BASE_URL).toString();

  let mainUrl = makeUrl(url);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(mainUrl);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setData(responseData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [url, options]);

  return [data, setData];
}
```

In `Forms.js`, `const [datasByParameter, setDatasByParameter]` I get like 100 rows of clients data, then the component creates the `form` dynamically based on the API return.

But the issue is that it gets a bit delayed when it occours the change event on inputs `const handleInputChange = (...) => responseData`. I still want to update the data without a submit button, that's why i'm allowing the edition and not allowing.

Demonstrative screenshot:
[image: Demonstrative screenshot]

By the way, I'd love the get some suggestions or snippets for bypass this problem